# Swagger integration with service built using filters

Tags: java, rest, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have a REST services which doesn't use any opensource rest library (jersey etc..) Its implemented using Filters/servlet.

Is it possible to generate a Swagger definition from such service by annotating the source code? If yes please share some details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Example](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-samples/tree/master/java/java-servlet)

[More information on Swagger-servlet modeule can be found here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150210114837/https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/tree/master/modules/swagger-servlet)